# Android: Calling another GridView Adapter through a single GridView Adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, mobile, android-adapter

First I populate an ArrayList on a GridView. Within that GridView I need to populate more data on another GridView. Basically call a second adapter from the first adapter.

My code so far:

```
    public class ProductGridInflator extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{
    ArrayList<Image> dbImages = new ArrayList<Image>();
    GridView multiplePics;
    Context ctx;
    public ProductGridInflator(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Product> objects, ArrayList<Image> obj) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.dbProducts = objects;
            this.ctx = context;
            this.resource = resource;
            this.dbImages = obj;
        }

    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View child = convertView;
            final RecordHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating your xml layout

            if (child == null) {            
                child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
                multiplePics = (GridView) child.findViewById(R.id.moreImagesGrid);
             }

    if(dbImages.size() > 1)
    {
        OtherImagesAdapter adapter = new OtherImagesAdapter(ctx, R.layout.grid_single, dbImages);
        multiplePics.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  return child;
}
```

Theoretically this is correct right. This doesn't seem to work. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: where is your variable dbImages? arent you missing `private ArrayList<Image> obj;` ?

Comment: Yeah I've declared those, I didn't add them to the question. If I add a Log.d to the dbImages.size() I get the correct number of images (count) as well. Its just that it doesn't reach the adapter or something @Vojtaaa9

Comment: I think that making a new adapter in getView() method is bad idea. 1st, it gets called many times, which means you create this big object a lot of times which can cause `OutOfMemory` error. 2nd you cant manage the adapter or the gridView. If you draw a schema or take a screenshot with some explaination, i'll be able to help you. Normally, you set this in your `Fragment`/`Activity`. I think, that creating adapter in another adapter is bad approach, but i have found no sources to this.